# How many render targets should I use?

Tags: xna, rendering, render, rendertarget

I need to do a lot of rotations, and instead of doing extra calculations, I could draw the image as if it was at zero degrees, and then rotate it to what ever degrees I want.

Problem is, I might end up doing this +200 times per second. Should I even bother going there?
Couldn't find the amount of render targets Xna could support. Would be glad if someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Just draw them with `SpriteBatch`

Comment: I'm trying to say that I need to do two rotations, one from the center of the image, and one from a certain point. SpriteBatch only allows for one rotation per image, so my question is should I draw it to a rendertarget with a rotation, and then draw the render target with another rotation? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way, I've never had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

The number of simultaneous render targets your graphics device supports is given by the [`MaxSimultaneousRenderTargets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevicecapabilities.maxsimultaneousrendertargets%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) property. There are numerous caveats for using multiple render targets.

Unfortunately, this appears to exist only until XNA 3.1.

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976073%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx).